# Why my tensor defined in forward function can not be transformed in to cuda variable autonomously?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

In PyTorch, in the `forward` function of a model

```
class my_model(torch.nn.module):

    ......

    def forward():
        self.a=torch.zeros(1)
        #blabla
```

After `model.cuda()`, why `self.a` is still a `cpu` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is so by design.

Only the tensors which are a part of the model will move with `model.cuda()` or `model.to("cuda")`.

These tensors are registered with `register_parameter` or `register_buffer`. This also includes child modules, parameters and buffers registered with the aforementioned functions.

Even though `self.a=torch.zeros(1)` is actually a part of the class itself, by design it will not be moved to CUDA, instead you would need to do `a.to("cuda")`, if you haven't used the `register*` methods.

Comment: One solution is check the device of whatever variable belongs to the model, and move my new variable there.

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```
device=whatever_parameter_in_your_forward_function_args.device
self.a=torch.zeros(1).to(device)
```